# Regex with multiple lines before end line

Tags: regex

Hello guys i have a question, i have a string like this:

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/3/0/0
 description PhysicalInterface
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/3/0/0.100
 description Vlan100
 dot1q vlan 100
!
multicast-routing
 address-family ipv4
 interface TenGigE0/2/0/0.3880
   ! Disable this interface under multicast-routing section:
   disable
  !
router static
 address-family ipv4 unicast
  GigabitEthernet0/3/1/4.3999 192.168.100.105
```

so i would like to use something like select everything between: interface and !
like:

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/3/0/0
     description PhysicalInterface
    !

interface GigabitEthernet0/3/0/0.100
     description Vlan100
     dot1q vlan 100
    !


interface TenGigE0/2/0/0.3880
       !
```

i have tried many different ways:

```
interface(.*?)\n
(interface(.*?)|\n{2,})
```

etc(i have forgotten every other ways)
what do you recommend guys?

Comment: A universal solution is `interface([\s\S]*?)!`. What is the regex flavor you have?

Comment: i use regex in sublime text

Comment: Then you can use a `(?s)interface.*?!` or `(?sm)^\s*interface\b.*?!`.

Comment: (?s)interface.*?! this one is simpler and easier to remember :D

Comment: If you want to give me credit for that, I can post :) I was on a laptop and lulling my child to sleep.

Comment: if you post i will :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to match some text including newlines between two strings, you need to use a lazy dot matching technique together with a DOTALL (or in other terminology, singleline) modifier: `.*?`.

When using PCRE regex patterns (SublimeText uses this regex flavor), you can use an inline version of this modifier: `(?s)`.

Lazy dot matching ensures a match between the start and leftmost end boundary. `1 q` will be matched in `1 q 4q` with the `1.*?q` pattern. Greedy matching, `1.*q`, would match that whole string.

So, in your case, you can use the following regex:

```
(?s)interface.*?!
|1 |   2     |3|4
```

Here,

1. The inline dotall modifier
2. Starting boundary, a literal `interface` string
3. Lazy dot maching construct
4. Literal `!` as an end boundary

Answer (score 1):

```
\binterface\b[\s\S]*?!
```

This should do it for you.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vV1wW6/45

Comment: Dude you saved my life ahahhaha :D

Comment: i can't now, it says 10 more minutes :S

Comment: I decided that since OP re-accepted the answer,  I owe you an upvote. Best regards!

Comment: @stribizhev hahaha np :)